# What type of file is the "sound fragment" parameter for audioop?

Tags: python, audio, beat-detection

The [Python audioop documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/audioop.html) states that most of the available functions require "sound fragments."

> The audioop module contains some useful operations on sound fragments. It operates on sound fragments consisting of signed integer samples 8, 16 or 32 bits wide, stored in Python strings.

What exactly is a sound fragment and how can I turn an existing .wav file into one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do so by using the [wave module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html)

The `open()` method opens the file and `readframes(n)` returns (maximum) n frames of audio as a string of bytes, just what audioop wants.

For example, let's say you need to use the `avg()` method from audioop. This is how you could do it:

```python
import wave
import audioop


wav = wave.open("piano2.wav")
print(audioop.avg(wav.readframes(wav.getnframes()), wav.getsampwidth()))
```

Outputs:

```
-2
```

Also, you may be interested in the `rewind()` method from the wave module. It puts the reading position back to the beginning of the wav file.

If you need to read through your wav file twice you can write this:

```python
wav = wave.open("piano2.wav")
print(audioop.avg(wav.readframes(wav.getnframes()), wav.getsampwidth()))

# if you don't call rewind, next readframes() call 
# will return nothing and audioop will fail

wav.rewind() 
print(audioop.max(wav.readframes(wav.getnframes()), wav.getsampwidth()))
```

Or alternatively you can cache the string:

```python
wav = wave.open("piano2.wav")
string_wav = wav.readframes(wav.getnframes())
print(audioop.avg(string_wav, wav.getsampwidth()))
# wav.rewind()
print(audioop.max(string_wav, wav.getsampwidth()))
```

Comment: Thanks for this, very thorough!

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look into the [`wave`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html) module. You probably want to open a file in read mode and use `readframes` to get the sample you need for `audiooop.`

Answer (score 2):

To answer what exactly a fragment is, it's a [bytes object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes), which is just a string of bytes. I believe that for 8-bit audio files, there would be one byte for each frame for 8-bit audio, two bytes per frame for 16-bit audio, and four bytes for 32-bit audio.

Answer (score 2):

A sound fragment represents a sequence of signed integer sound samples encoded in a bytes-like object. `audioop` supports representations of 1, 2, 3 or 4 bytes per sample.

A single sample can be converted with `struct.pack` (let's use 0, 1, 2, -1, 42 as examples):

```py
from struct import pack

for sample in [0, 1, 2, -1, 42]:
   print(f'sample value {sample}, 1 byte/sample:', pack('b', sample))
   print(f'             {sample}, 2 byte/sample:', pack('h', sample))
   print(f'             {sample}, 4 byte/sample:', pack('i', sample))
```

This prints:

```
sample value 0, 1 byte/sample: b'\x00'
             0, 2 byte/sample: b'\x00\x00'
             0, 4 byte/sample: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'
sample value 1, 1 byte/sample: b'\x01'
             1, 2 byte/sample: b'\x01\x00'
             1, 4 byte/sample: b'\x01\x00\x00\x00'
sample value 2, 1 byte/sample: b'\x02'
             2, 2 byte/sample: b'\x02\x00'
             2, 4 byte/sample: b'\x02\x00\x00\x00'
sample value -1, 1 byte/sample: b'\xff'
             -1, 2 byte/sample: b'\xff\xff'
             -1, 4 byte/sample: b'\xff\xff\xff\xff'
sample value 42, 1 byte/sample: b'*'
             42, 2 byte/sample: b'*\x00'
             42, 4 byte/sample: b'*\x00\x00\x00'
```

Let's assume we want to convert some sound samples we have in Python (signed) integer representation to a sound fragment using 2 byte per sample (allowing input sample values between -32768 to 32767; that is `-2**15` to `2**15-1`) like used in an audio CD:

```py
import audioop
import array

samples = [0, 1000, 32767, 1, -1, -32768, -1000]  # 7 samples of "music"
fragment = array.array('h', samples).tobytes()
print(f'Fragment {fragment} of length {len(fragment)}')

# convert back with audioop function
print([audioop.getsample(fragment, 2, i) for i in range(len(fragment) // 2)])
```

This prints:

```
Fragment b'\x00\x00\xe8\x03\xff\x7f\x01\x00\xff\xff\x00\x80\x18\xfc' of length 14
[0, 1000, 32767, 1, -1, -32768, -1000]
```

As last example, write a 3 second stereo sine wave as `.wav` file and read it again:

```py
import audioop
import wave
from array import array
from math import sin, pi

bytes_per_sample = 2
duration = 3.  # seconds
sample_rate = 16000.  # Hz
frequency = 440.  # Hz
max_amplitude = 2**(bytes_per_sample * 8 - 1) - 1
amp = max_amplitude * 0.8
time = [i / sample_rate for i in range(int(sample_rate * duration))]
samples = [int(round(amp * sin(2 * pi * frequency * t))) for t in time]
fragment_mono = array('h', samples).tobytes()
fragment_stereo = audioop.tostereo(fragment_mono, bytes_per_sample, 1, 1)
with wave.open('sine_440hz_stereo.wav', 'wb') as wav:
    wav.setnchannels(2)  # stereo
    wav.setsampwidth(bytes_per_sample)
    wav.setframerate(sample_rate)
    wav.writeframes(fragment_stereo)

# read wave file again
with wave.open('sine_440hz_stereo.wav', 'rb') as wav:
    fragment = wav.readframes(wav.getnframes())

# test whether written fragment and read fragment are same
assert fragment == fragment_stereo
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import audioop
import wave
read = wave.open("C:/Users/Pratik/sampy/cat.wav")
string_wav = read.readframes(read.getnframes())
a = audioop.lin2alaw(string_wav,read.getsampwidth())
print(a)
----------------------------------------------------------
how to convert wav file  to alaw
```